# Why my test keeps getting skipped? (Using WebDriver.io and cucumber)

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, webdriver-io, gherkin

I am trying to run my test, but the result is some of my scenario test is getting skipped:

**`step-definitions` file:**

```js
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@wdio/cucumber-framework');

const MainPage = require('../pageobjects/main-page.js');
const ElementsPage = require('../pageobjects/elements-page.js');
const ButtonsPage = require('../pageobjects/buttons-page.js')


Given('I am on the Main Page', async () => {
    await MainPage.open(`https://demoqa.com/`)
});

When('I click Elements Button', async() => {
    await MainPage.clickElements()
});

Then('I successfully go to <string> Page', async(namePage) => {
    await ElementsPage.verifyClickButton(namePage)
});

When('I click Button on Navbar', async() => {
    await ElementsPage.clickBtnButtons()
});

Then('I successfully open {string} Page', async(buttons) => {
    await ButtonsPage.verifyNamePage(buttons)
});

When('I click on Click Me Button', async() => {
    await ButtonsPage.clickBtnClickMe()
});

Then('I successfully click on Click Me Button', async() => {
    await ButtonsPage.verifyClickMeButton()
});

When('I click on Right Click Me Button', async() => {
    await ButtonsPage.clickBtnRightClickMe()
});

Then('I successfully click on Right Click Me Button', async() => {
    await ButtonsPage.verifyRightClickMeButton()
});

When('I click on Double Click Me Button', async() => {
    await ButtonsPage.clickBtnDoubleClickMe()
});

Then('I successfully click on Double Click Me Button', async() => {
    await ButtonsPage.verifyDoubleClickMeButton()
});
```

Since there are no errors, I am wondering what should I do?

**Console-logs:**

```
 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] Running: chrome (v108.0.5359.125) on windows
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] Session ID: 86891a0c4203314f998ad2a06ab208a6
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] » \features\scenarios\buttons.feature
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] Latihan Automation di demoqa.com
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] Successfully click 3 Buttons in Elements Page
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    ✓ Given I am on the Main Page
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    ✓ When I click Elements Button
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    ✓ Then I successfully go to "Elements" Page
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    ✓ When I click Button on Navbar
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    - Then I successfully open "Buttons" Page
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    - When I click on Click Me Button
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    - Then I successfully click on Click Me Button
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    - When I click on Right Click Me Button
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    - Then I successfully click on Right Click Me Button
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]    - Then I successfully click on Double Click Me Button
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0]
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] 4 passing (37.2s)
[chrome 108.0.5359.125 windows #0-0] 7 skipped


Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:42

2022-12-20T08:58:07.664Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2022-12-20T08:58:07.927Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2022-12-20T08:58:07.929Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

Am I am missing some configurations here? I don't know what to try, it is my first time using WebdriverIO.

Comment: What does your feature file look like?

Comment: The only difference I see among your step definitions is that you used `{string}` in one place and `<string>` in another place. Adding more details as @Raju mentioned could help  or link your repo.

Comment: You ARE getting errors and logs, you just don't know where to look for them. Try to either comment-out `outputDir` in your `wdio.conf.js` file, to have the logs dumped into your terminal, or go and read your debug folder: start with the `wdio-<index>-<index>` logs. ;)

Comment: Update your question with your errors when you find them. Else, there is little anyone can help you with.

Comment: I could not tell you the exact solution because I would need to see your whole project structure. However, I can tell you your steps are being skipped because cucumber is not finding step definitions.

If you're using gradle try checking cucumber glue (where does your step definition point to). It might be as simple as a typo in the definitions class.